# MAUI: How to remove ViewCell from the current view

Tags: maui

I'm currently developing my first MAUI application, and I'm facing a challenge regarding the removal of a ViewCell once the corresponding object is deleted. I have managed to successfully delete the object from the database, but I'm unsure about the proper approach to remove it from the UI.

Below is the XAML design of the ViewCell. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Latest notifications" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,20,0,0" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#013270"/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <!-- List Of Schedules -->
                <ListView x:Name="ListOfNotifications" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowHeight="100" SelectionMode="Single" ItemSelected="ListOfNotifications_ItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Padding="10,0,80,0" BackgroundColor="#F6FAFF" CornerRadius="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="90">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Editor Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#063d8b" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True"  AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
                                            <Label x:Name="LblId" Text="{Binding Id}" IsVisible="false"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="#3E8EED"  CornerRadius="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Frame_Tapped" />
                                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label Text="X" FontSize="Small" TextColor="#FFF" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="20,0,20,0"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

NotificationPage.cs

```
    private List<Notification> _notifications;
    public NotificationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        
        // Get user menu
        string token = Preferences.Get("accesstoken", string.Empty);

        // Remove the "Bearer " prefix
        string tokenValue = token.Split(' ')[0];

        // Decode the token
        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(tokenValue);

        // Extract the role claim
        var personalIdClaim = jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "PersonalId").Value;
        if (personalIdClaim is not null)
        {
            List<Notification> userNotifications = await ApiService.LatestNotifications(Convert.ToInt32(personalIdClaim));
            ListOfNotifications.ItemsSource = userNotifications;
            _notifications = new List<Notification>(userNotifications);
        }
        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }

    private async void Frame_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        var frame = (Frame)sender;
        var parentGrid = (Grid)frame.Parent;
        var viewCell = (ViewCell)parentGrid.Parent;
        var lblId = (Label)frame.FindByName("LblId");

        // Get the corresponding item and remove it from the ObservableCollection
        var itemToRemove = (Notification)viewCell.BindingContext;
        _notifications.Remove(itemToRemove);


        if (lblId != null)
        {
            var id = lblId.Text;
            await ApiService.DeleteNotification(id.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ListOfNotifications.ItemsSource = _notifications;
        }
        ActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        ActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
    }
```

[image: img]

Comment: you don't directly manipulate the UI of a templated control.  You remove the element from the `ItemsSource`.  Since you are using an `ObservableCollection`, the UI should automatically referesh when an item is added or removed

Comment: also, you are setting `ItemsSource` in both the XAML and the code behind.  Pick one or the other, not both.

Comment: and... you should be able to get the `BindingContext` directly from the `Frame`, you should not have to do all that work to find each child element

Comment: Thank you Jason for the advice! As I mentioned, this is my first MAUI application, and it is a little tricky since everything is new. Can you express your answer in code, please?

Comment: Your code as written might work - you need to use the debugger to verify that `        notifications.Remove(itemToRemove);` is actually updating the collection as expected

Comment: with debugging, I can see that the item is removed. But the UI list is not updated

Comment: @Jason alright I updated the code since I found the solution. Although there is a bug, I can not remove more then one item, if I click on another one it will be deleted but not from the UI, I need to visit another page and return back to be deleted.

Comment: you are assigning `ItemsSource` multiple times in the code - that makes it much harder to debug.  Do it once.

Comment: @Jason I switch to CollectionView and the problem is solved.

Comment: Please add "Your Answer" below, with the solution. This helps others with similar problem later.